# accessing help functions and auto-suggesting arguments in python (jupyter lab)

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I just started switching from R to python, and may I ask about some very basic questions?

There are two nice properties that Rstudio has, which I haven't figure out how to do with python. For example, I'm trying to use the dot product function such as `numpy.array([1,2]).dot(numpy.array([3,4]))`.

**Problem 1**: In R, if I move the cursor into a function, the possible arguments that I can potentially use will be shown, as demonstrated in the figure below. However, I don't see this in python (jupyter lab).
[image]
**Problem 2**: for the help document regarding the function, in R I would just type `?functionName()`, but in python I don't really know how to get the help documents. `help(numpy.array)` returns me a full list of everything, and I was wondering if there is a way for it to return only the help document for the dot product function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1**: you can press `Shift+Tab` after placing cursor on the function in question for a snippet of documentation. Press `Shift+Tab+Tab` for a more detailed one.

**Problem 2**: you can run the same command as R but just drop the brackets. 
e.g. `?numpy.dot`